# Modal no se cierra después de enviar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo 3 modals en una misma página que uno añade usuario, otro edita y otro elimina. 
Cuando los llamo le doy a Enviar y se queda el mismo congelado hasta que no refresco y me hace los cambios.

Estoy usando 3 javascript para cada uno de los modals, uno `add_user`, otro `update_user` y el último `delete_user`. He cambiado varias veces el boton de submit cambiándolo por un input pero nada. No consigo que funcione.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addBookDialog_delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" id="delete_dlg">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="delete_user" method="post">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h5 class="modal-title pull-left">Delete user</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input name="operacion" value="delete_user" id="operacion" type="hidden">
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="form-control" id="userId" value=""/>
                    Are you sure, you want to delete this user?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button name="delete_user" class="btn btn-link">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery("#delete_user").bind('click',function(e){ alert('aqui');
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = jQuery(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "operaciones.php",
                data: formData,
                success: function(html){
                    if (html.toString() == 'true')
                    {
                        $.jGrowl("User deleted", { header: ';)' });
                        var delay = 2000;
                        setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'admin_user.php'  }, delay);  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $.jGrowl("Data Already Exist.", { header: 'Try again.' });
                    }
                $('#delete_dlg').modal('hide');
                }

            });
            return false;
            //$('#delete_form').modal('hide');
        });
```

**OPERACIONES.PHP**

```
<?php include('dbcon.php'); 

$operacion = $_POST['operacion'];

if ($operacion == 'save_user') {
    echo 'true';

}
else if ($operacion == 'update_user') {
    ...
    echo 'true';    


} else if ($operacion == 'delete_user') {
    ...
    echo 'true';
} ?>
```

Comment: Hola, la estructura de elementos html se está solapando. Debes ajustarla antes de continuar las pruebas. Y, puedes dar orden de cerrar el modal antes de terminar `success:` en el bloque ajax

Comment: El problema creo que es que una vez dentro del php no devuelve el echo true o false al ajax ni refresca

Comment: Eso es de esperar porque se está solapando la estructura y vas a tener comportamientos inesperados, dependen de que el navegador "tenga la gentileza" de entenderla al crear el DOM. Por eso te dije que debes ajustarla antes. Y para cerrar usar algo como `$('tuModal').modal('hide');`

Comment: Nota, en el selector que usé no puse almohadilla para indicar que usas un id, se me fue un gazapo usa `$('#tuModal').modal('hide');`

Comment: Gracias, sí lo entendí. Voy a ver que tal y comento

Comment: Hola, en el código que muestras <form> se abre dentro de encabezado y se cierra dentro de footer. Y, footer no cierra al igual que content, el navegador fue muy gentil al mostrate algo. Pon el <form> despues de content y antes de abrir header. y cierralo luego de cerrar footer y antes de cerrar content, que debes cerrar. Ten cuidado de que todos los divs cierren.

Comment: Incluso corrigiendo eso se queda congelado en el modal :( ... me deja cerrar si cambio de button a input pero de todas formas no funciona bien

Comment: cambia `jQuery("#delete_form").submit(function(e){` por `jQuery("#delete_user").bind('click',function(e){` y antes de salir de `succes:` cierras el dialogo con `$('#delete_dlg').modal('hide');` y al div contenedor cuya clase es modal-dialog ponle `id="delete_dlg"` Ah! y cambia `var formData = jQuery("#delete_form").serialize();` por `var formData = jQuery(this).serialize();`

Comment: adicionalmente en lugar de `jQuery(` puedes usar `$(`

Comment: Perfecto, ahora me abre y me cierra bien los modals... el tema es que no hace nada, es decir, que parece que no llega a entrar al php... cada form es form id="add_form" ... "update form" o "delete_form" y el submit <button name="add_user" class="btn btn-link">Add</button> y los demas con el name="update_user" y "delete_user"

Comment: No es que no haga nada. Estas validando mal la respuesta. debes hacer: `if (html.toString() === 'true'){ ... };` en lugar de `if(html=='true')`

Comment: Hola, la página no se te refresca por que cancelas el comportamiento por defecto del submit con le sentencia **e.repventDefault()**.

Comment: He editado el código y puesto lo que tengo ahora... con los cambios ahora me sigue sin actualizar y se queda el modal congelado. Cuando refresco con F5 se ven los cambios hechos. Parece ser que se queda dentro del jquery y no sale.

Comment: 1. debes leer la documentcion [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) 2. para cerrar el modal debes hacer referencia al disparador en tu caso de ser `$("#addBookDialog_delete").modal('hide');` y no es necesario el `return false` saludos!

Comment: Gracias... era eso por el que no cerraba. Lo puse y funciona perfectamente. Gracias por vuestro tiempo de verdad. Un abrazo!